# D3.js Force directed graph different shapes for nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am currently developing a visualization using D3.js where I am displaying the data in a force-directed graph. As data in JSON format has 6 different types of nodes so I want to display them in different shapes like circle, rectangle, square etc. I had gone through the following blogs

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062383

http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116

http://bl.ocks.org/FrissAnalytics/a63553129a896159c07b71dd3ede35d7

http://bl.ocks.org/fzyukio/563059b1bff8901dc3beaf1150934323

But I did not understand the logic of how did the append different shapes. I do not want to use symbols as I had tried them and they are too small were distorting my visualization. So Please let me know how can I display different shapes for my nodes.

Comment: If the only reason you haven't used d3 symbols was their size, d3 symbols can be resized.

Comment: @AndrewReid  I tried to implement by following your blog. when I try to increase the size then my graph is getting distorted I had added to follow code to increase the size .size(function (d) { return 5})

Comment: I have a very similar situation but in my case it's not just force network, I have many diagram types and want to use common symbology across all of them. Did you ever find an answer to this question?